# Get all search results from Google search page

Tags: java, selenium

I want to get the search result from google after I type some string for search. How I can do this with Selenium? So far I managed to create this:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
        searchBox.submit();

        System.out.println("Current Url: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

        List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class=r]/a"));

        for(int i=0; i<results.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(">>>>> results " + results.get(i).getText());
        }

        // second attempt

        List<WebElement> allSearchResults = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ol li h3>a"));

        //iterate the above list to get all the search titles & links from that page
        for (WebElement eachResult : allSearchResults)
        {
            System.out.println("Title : " + eachResult.getText() + ", Link : " + eachResult.getAttribute("href"));
        }
```

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [*wait for the results to appear*](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) after submitting the search form:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3.r a")));
```

Comment: @PeterPenzov after submitting and before searching for the links.

Comment: By the way do you know why the second list of results is not working? I would like also to fix it.

Comment: @PeterPenzov sure, the `h3 > a` is not inside the `ol li` on the page - hence, nothing matched the `ol li h3>a` selector. Btw, you can experiment with the CSS selectors using the console in the Browser Developer Tools and `$` and `$$` functions. E.g.: `> $$('h3 > a')`.

Comment: @PeterPenzov just open your chrome developer tools, console tab and play around with CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track. It seems that your xpath is incorrect. you are missing single quote next to r

```
List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class=r]/a"));
```

Should be

```
 List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a"));
```

[screenshot of google search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4rsr.png)

Comment: Thanks, but again I get empty result. Any idea why?